# php: interface inheritance: add optional parameter in child interface

Tags: php

The following seems to work ok in PHP 5.5.6, but not in PHP 5.3:
(following [this bug report](https://drupal.org/node/2195859) on a piece of code I wrote)
(supposed error message is `Fatal error: Can't inherit abstract function ...`)

```
interface A {
  function foo($a);
}

interface B extends A {
  function foo($a, $b = NULL);
}
```

In my understanding this does not violate the LSP principle. You are not allowed to narrow down the signature, but you should be allowed to losen it..

The purpose of this is I have an interface A that I cannot change for BC, but then I still want to introduce the additional parameter. This seemed to work all fine until this bug report showed up.

Is this simply a PHP version thing?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be indeed a version thing.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21381524/246724:

> "it helped upgrading from PHP 5.3.8 to PHP 5.3.28."