# Interface with no parameters

Tags: php

I have a question about interfaces. Can I have an interface specify a method with no parameters, but still have parameters in the class?

```
interface FooInterface {
    public function bar();
}

class Foo implements FooInterface {
    public function bar($parameters = array())
    {
        return 'bar';
    }
}
```

I don't get an error doing this locally in PHP 5.5.10, but do in PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: Why declare a specific function signature in an interface just to violate that declaration later on? Interfaces are specifically there so you know what you can expect; if you're changing the expectations anyway, then what's the point?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the declaration of the `bar` method in the `Foo` class is actually not compatible with the declaration in `FooInterface`.

`FooInterface::bar` is a method with no parameters, `Foo::bar` has one parameter (though an optional one). This throws an exception in earlier PHP 5.4.x versions.

Apparently, in later versions the PHP devs have decided that it's ok to declare a method with more parameters than the interface or parent class, as long as the parameters are optional.

**EDIT:**

[The PHP documentation states:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

> Furthermore the signatures of the methods must match, i.e. the type hints and the number of required arguments must be the same. For example, **if the child class defines an optional argument, where the abstract method's signature does not, there is no conflict in the signature.**

So the behaviour you're experiencing appears to be a bug in earlier versions of PHP. Unfortunately, I was not able to find a bug report or release note which would indicate when, and for which PHP versions, the bug was fixed.

The lowest version I could test on right now was PHP 5.4.9, and the bug appears to be fixed there, as I could run the code without errors.

Comment: Can you provide official statements / articles / etc to back up your last paragraph? *Aparently X* is not a reliable bit of information.

Comment: Yeah, searching for official release notes, until then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525620/php-fatal-error-cant-inherit-abstract-function/21381524#21381524