# Fatal error: Can't inherit abstract function TranslatorInterface::translate()

Tags: zend-framework2, version, composer-php

I'm new for ZF2, I have a problem after downloading ZF2 and trying to start the Skeleton Application.

```
Fatal error: Can't inherit abstract function Zend\Validator\Translator\TranslatorInterface::translate() (previously declared abstract in Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface) in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2crud\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator.php on line 19
```

OS: Windows 7,
PHP: PHP 5.3.8,
ZF2 Version: 2.4.1

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Update your PHP, it is severely outdated and has a bug until your version 5.3.8. It is fixed in 5.3.9 and above.

Details here: [PHP Fatal error: Can't inherit abstract function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525620/php-fatal-error-cant-inherit-abstract-function) (found by googling your error message string).

Additionally, I wonder where you got that ZF2 version 2.4.1, because it isn't tagged on Github nor released at http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest yet.